# Convert XML to Json - XMLObjectifier is not defined

Tags: javascript, json, xml

I have my code like this one:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
  var json = XMLObjectifier.xmlToJSON(xmlhttp.responseXML);
  var result = json.Body[0].GetQuoteResponse[0].GetQuoteResult[0].Text;
  json = XMLObjectifier.xmlToJSON(XMLObjectifier.textToXML(result));
  alert(symbol + ' Stock Quote: $' + json.Stock[0].Last[0].Text); 
 }
}
```

I got an error **XMLObjectifier is not defined** what can I do?

Thanks,
Lucero

Comment: Are you including https://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlobjectifier/ in your project?

Comment: I'm already download the file that you mentioned, need do some references or something like that?

Comment: ya, if you want to include it you'll need to put a script tag in your HTML page.

Comment: Thank so much, I did it and I got a correct functionality

Comment: I added an answer to your question so you can mark this as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error, "is not defined" usually means you're missing a library.

Please check that you've got https://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlobjectifier/ included into your project.